Integral inequality on $[0,1]$
I found the following question on another forum and unfortunately I don't have any additional information about it:
Let $f$ be non-negative and square integrable on $[0,1]$. Prove that
$$\left(\int_0^1 xf(x)\text{d}x\right)\left(\int_0^1 f^2 (x)\text{d}x\right)\geq\frac{4}{9}\left(\int_0^1 f(x)\text{d}x\right)^3.$$
I tried the usual Cauchy inequality tricks but nothing worked. I don't know if the inequality is tight, but I couldn't find an equality case.

Why bother being coy about the source --- what forum? Do you have a link?

Nothing coy about it, it is artofproblemsolving.com

That context is helpful to edit into the post (with a link). I thought for a bit that the $\frac49$ on the RHS could be changed to $\frac12$, but then saw that for the example $f(x) = \cos\frac{\pi x}2$, the LHS is $\frac1\pi-\frac2{\pi^2}$ and the cubed integral on the RHS is $\frac8{\pi^3}$, whose ratio is $\frac{\pi(\pi-2)}8 \approx 0.448302 \approx 1.00868 \cdot \frac49$.

$f(x) = 1-x$ yields equality. It's also probably significant that $\frac{4}{9} = {\left(\int_0^1 x^{1/2}dx\right)}^2$.

Remarks. This is a variant of something I wrote some years ago. I learned this trick from @fedja (in other words, the solution is due to @fedja).
Proof.
We have, for any $b > 0, x \ge 0$,
$$b^2 x + \frac{1}{b}(b - b^3 x)^{+} \ge 1 \tag{1}$$
where $(y)^{+} = \max(0, y)$.
(Note: If $b^2 x \ge 1$, (1) is true. If $b^2x < 1$,
then $b^2 x + \frac{1}{b}(b - b^3 x)^{+} = b^2x + \frac{1}{b}(b - b^3x) = 1$.)
Using (1) and Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have, for any $b > 0$,
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^1 f(x) \,\mathrm{d} x
 &\le \int_0^1 \left(b^2 x + \frac{1}{b}(b - b^3 x)^{+}\right)f(x)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &= b^2 \int_0^1 xf(x)\,\mathrm{d} x
 + \frac{1}{b}\int_0^1 (b - b^3 x)^{+} f(x)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &\le b^2 \int_0^1 xf(x)\,\mathrm{d} x
 + \frac{1}{b}\sqrt{\int_0^1 \left[(b - b^3 x)^{+}\right]^2 \,\mathrm{d} x}\sqrt{\int_0^1 f^2(x)\,\mathrm{d} x}\\
 &\le b^2 \int_0^1 xf(x)\,\mathrm{d} x
 + \frac{1}{b}\sqrt{\frac13}\sqrt{\int_0^1 f^2(x)\,\mathrm{d} x} \tag{2}
\end{align*}
where we use
$$\int_0^1 \left[(b - b^3 x)^{+}\right]^2 \,\mathrm{d} x
\le \int_0^{1/b^2} (b - b^3x)^2 \,\mathrm{d} x
= \frac13. \tag{3}
$$
Let
$$A := \int_0^1 xf(x)\,\mathrm{d} x,
\quad B := \sqrt{\frac13}\sqrt{\int_0^1 f^2(x)\,\mathrm{d} x}.$$
Since (2) holds for any $b > 0$, we choose
$$b = \sqrt[3]{\frac12 \cdot \frac{1}{A} \cdot B}$$
to obtain $\int_0^1 f(x) \,\mathrm{d} x \le \frac32\sqrt[3]{2AB^2}$ or
$$\int_0^1 f(x) \,\mathrm{d} x
\le \frac32\sqrt[3]{\frac23}\sqrt[3]{\int_0^1 xf(x)\,\mathrm{d} x}\sqrt[3]{\int_0^1 f^2(x)\,\mathrm{d} x}$$
which results in
$$\left(\int_0^1 xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\left(\int_0^1 f^2 (x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\ge\frac{4}{9}\left(\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)^3.$$
We are done.
